# Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter 'xx' declared.Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint

Tags: ios, flutter-ios, flutter-add-to-app

**Steps to reproduce**

NO.1 Create the following Dart program:

(1) main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void test() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Flutter Demo'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(2) pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
```

(3) flutter doctor

```
/Users/dqs/Documents/CompanyProjects/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at /Users/dqs/Documents/CompanyProjects/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (4 weeks ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

NO.2 ~ Create the following iOS program:

(1) BaseFlutterController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

class BaseFlutterController: FlutterViewController {
    
    override init(engine: FlutterEngine, nibName: String?, bundle nibBundle: Bundle?) {
        super.init(engine: engine, nibName: nibName, bundle: nibBundle)
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
}
```

(2) TestController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FlutterPluginRegistrant

class TestController: BaseFlutterController {
    
    init(withEntrypoint entryPoint: String?) {
      let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      let newEngine = appDelegate.flutterEngines.makeEngine(withEntrypoint: entryPoint, libraryURI: nil)
      // register third-party packages
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: newEngine)
      super.init(engine: newEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
    }
}
```

(3) AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    //MARK: Flutter Engines
    lazy var flutterEngines = FlutterEngineGroup(name: "native_flutter_engine_group", project: nil)
```

(4) enter flutter screen

```
let testVC = TestController(withEntrypoint: "test")
navigationController?.pushViewController(testVC, animated: true)
```

...then run the app on an iOS device.

**Expected behavior**

Expect test() to be run as the program's entry-point, yielding a normal flutter screen.

**Actual behavior**

The app runs well in **debug** mode, but fails in **release** mode with the following error:

```
[768:219965] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter 'test' declared.
Receiver: top-level
Tried calling: test, stack trace: #0      NoSuchMethodError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:222)
[768:219965] [VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(681)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(165)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
[768:219965] [VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(381)] Could not create root isolate.
[768:219965] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(580)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

**My try**

When I removed the 'shared_preferences: ^2.0.13' package from the 'pubspec.yaml', it worked well in both **debug** and **release** mode.
Then I also tried other packages(local-storage related and others), I found that once I used packages about local storage (e.g. shared_preferences、cached_network_image ...), the problem showed up definitely, and when I removed them, everything was ok. (All the local- storage related packages, like the shared_preferences, works well in **pure Flutter** project in both **debug** and **release** mode, but **not worked** in **iOS x Flutter** project in **release** mode.)

PS:When we enter flutter module by the following

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
```

instead of

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void test() => runApp(const MyApp());
```

No Problem!!!

Comment: Oh No !!! The #url_launcher# package has the same question !!! It seems that packages  with the ability to interact with native platform may encounter this problem.

Comment: Beta Channel 2.13.0-0.4.pre has solved the issue!!!